# 2.1 (ReflectionException): Class ... does not exist

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping

I wrote a custom shipping module for Magento 2.0 that adds an LTL/Fright option. It worked in Magento 2.0.7, and I was recently testing 2.1.7. It appears all of my other (self authored) modules work, but my Shipping module does not.

After adding an item to the cart, and going to `http://localhost/checkout/cart` I get the following error:

```
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Comstar\Tli\Model\Carrier does not exist
#0 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Comstar\\Tli\\Mod...')
#1 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Comstar\\Tli\\Mod...')
#2 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Comstar\\Tli\\Mod...')
#3 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Comstar\\Tli\\Mod...', Array)
#4 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\module-shipping\Model\CarrierFactory.php(74): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Comstar\\Tli\\Mod...')
#5 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\module-shipping\Model\Config.php(65): Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory->create('tli', NULL)
#6 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider.php(590): Magento\Shipping\Model\Config->getActiveCarriers()
#7 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider.php(292): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider->getActiveCarriers()
#8 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider->getConfig()
#9 D:\Web\html\var\generation\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', Array, Array)
#10 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider.php(32): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->getConfig()
#11 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping.php(54): Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider->getConfig()
#12 D:\Web\html\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\shipping.phtml(28): Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Shipping->getCheckoutConfig()
.... (stack trace continues to 95 lines)
```

**app/code/Comstar/Tli/Model/Carrier.php**

```
namespace Comstar\Tli\Model;

[... class imports ...]

class Carrier extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    [... var declarations ...]

    public function __construct([... DI ...])
    {
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $errorFactory, $log, $data)
    }
}
```

**app/code/Comstar/Tli/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <tli>
                <active>1</active>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <allowed_methods>AACR,AACT</allowed_methods>
                <model>Comstar\Tli\Model\Carrier</model>
                <type>LTL</type>
                <title>Freight</title>
                <name>Comstar LTL</name>
                <specificerrmsg>There are no LTL Quotes available for this shipment.</specificerrmsg>
                <min_package_weight>125</min_package_weight>
                <max_package_weight>10000</max_package_weight>
            </tli>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

The Class `Comstar\Tli\Model\Carrier` clearly exists, and as I said, this module worked in 2.0.7. I did a quick review of `Magento_Ups` to see if anything major changed in the way shipping modules are loaded, but it doesn't appear to be built any differently.

I am running on `WAMP 3.0.9`, `PHP 7.0.21`. I updated from 2.0.7 to 2.1.7 by deleting the `/vendor/` folder and copying all 2.1.7 files into the Magento 2 root.

Why isn't Magento 2.1 able to find my Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out on this particular file, I had opened with a `<?` tag instead of a `<?php` tag. I'm not sure if it was the newer version of WAMP or PHP that triggered that sensitivity, but using `<?php` fixed the problem!

Comment: old post but - worth noting php.ini setting allow_short_open_tags (or something similar) - setting that to yes allows use of `<?`

Answer (score 10):

I my case,

[image]

I had actually a syntax error in the constructor. but it was not shown as usual errors with line number.
I ran,

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

It displayed there is a syntax error and showed line number.
Then updgrade,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

and deploy,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

for developer mode,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

It may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, `setup:di:compile` is the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use

```
setup:di:compile
```

command.

Also, try to remove var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/*

and run

```
setup:upgrade
```

command.

Comment: I'm in developer mode with the cache disabled. I ran `setup:di:compile` anyway, and it only moves the error to the PHP log and changes the stack trace a little.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this, Hope some one will be get help

- cd magento2.3.x

  > find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec
  >   chmod g+w {} +
  >
  > find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec
  >   chmod g+ws {} +
  >
  > chown -R :www-data .
  >
  > chmod u+x bin/magento

Answer (score 0):

Log into your server and cd into Magento's root directory and run:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that it might be a result of PHP Strict type:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

I removed this in my custom module, In case this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of the class used in dependency injection.

In my case, the error occurred when I had the following class in DI:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Mode\ResourceModel\Product
```

instead of

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
```

Note the difference between "`Mode`" and "`Model`".