# Error after installing Simiconnetor app builder in magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, exception, app

after installing when i'm tring to access the general setting n simi option i'm getting the followings error

```
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Simi\Simiconnector\Model\Config\Source\ViewType does not exist
```

Comment: Remove the following files

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched stack exchange already? I don't know this plugin but this error sounds very similar to one that can be solved by doing this:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/237872/70343

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following files

```
rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed var/di generated/*
```

After this run these commands to generate the files once again

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Please also ensure that var, pub and generated folders has the correct permissions